# Change class style in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the style of a class, I know this is a pretty simple question but already tried google and cant find how to do it, this is my code but its not working I get Syntax error

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop()> 620) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search").style.position = ¨sticky;¨
    $('.advanced-search').fadeIn();
   }
```

Comment: What are those things around the words sticky in `¨sticky;¨`? They're not quotes. And if you're using jQuery (which you should tag your question with assuming you are), use `$('.advanced-search').css('position','sticky')` not `document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search").style.position`

Comment: Yeah your syntax error is the quotes that aren't real quotes. Otherwise this is fine

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns and `HTMLCollection` which is an array-like obbject. It will not have `.style.position` properties. Since you are already using jQuery just query the selector using that.

```
var $el = $('.advanced-search');
$el.css('position', 'fixed');
$el.fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), emphasis mine:

> ***Returns an array-like object*** of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

`style` is not a property of a list; you must either iterate through each element and apply style or select an element out of the list.

One way to do this would be to turn the result of `getElementsByClassName` into an array an iterate over it:

```
var advSearches = document.getElementsByClassName('advanced-search');

advSearches = Array.prototype.slice.call(advSearches);

advSearches.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.position = 'sticky';
});
```

Or, condensed with ES6 destructuring:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('advanced-search')]
    .map(e => e.style.position = 'sticky');
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search")` is an array and you can't straightly add styles to all of them entirely just like that way you've used!
use `for loop` or `foreach`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop()> 620) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("advanced-search");
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            x[i].style.position = ¨sticky;¨
        }
        $('.advanced-search').fadeIn();
   }
});
```